# Switch item always return null

Tags: android, android-studio

I have switch item inside the navigation drawer(activity_main_drawer.xml) and I got a reference to it in the mainactivity.java as following

```
Switch s = findViewById(R.id.switch);
```

before I perform any task using it I check if it is null

```
if(s != null){....}
```

android studio gives me a warning saying "condition is always true",However, when I run it I get nullpointerexception, Here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_draw, R.id.dark_mode)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    Switch s = findViewById(R.id.dark_mode);
    if(sharedPreferences.getInt("DARK_MODE", 0)  == 1){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        s.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        s.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (s != null){
        s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    mEditor.putInt("DARK_MODE", 1);
                    mEditor.apply();
                }
                else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    mEditor.putInt("DARK_MODE", 0);
                    mEditor.apply();
                }
            }
        });}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if condition will always be true because you will always run `s.setchecked` method before reaching that if statement, so if s object is already null an exception will be thrown and the condition checking if the object is null will never be reached.

Comment: sorry, I pressed undo before I post so a part of the post got deleted, I edited it,
Yes, you're right I receive an exception at that method that s is null and that was my actual problem

Comment: @ZiyadTarek No problem at all, please mark this answer as the right one for your question.